# Resources for applications of Keldysh Green's functions

Tags: resource-recommendations, many-body, greens-functions

I am looking for resources to learn Keldysh formulation of Green's functions. I am especially interested in learning how they are applied to calculate transport characteristics.

Most of the books I could find introduce the definitions of the formalism but never apply it to concrete physical realizations. So I am looking for an **applied** reference on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a tutorial paper, written by A.P. Jauho, to introduce the Keldysh formalism.](http://isis.ku.dk/kurser/blob.aspx?feltid=55674)

[For application in transport here is a nice paper.](http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.94.045424)